# jQuery will not fire from external js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

Yes, I know there are many posts on this subject, I've read a great majority of them, but to no avail. This works coming from the external file,

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
 alert("Ready")
 });
```

but this doesn't,

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
$('#<%=RadioButtonList1.ClientID %> input').change(function () { 
  $("#HiddenField1").val((this).value); //places selected value in HiddenField1
  });
});

$(document).ready(function () {  
$("#Button1").mouseenter(function () { //see if Texture and Color Selections were made
    var z = $("#HiddenField1").val(); //
    //alert(z)
    if (z != "xx") { // a Product was chosen
        var t = $("#DropDownList1").val(); // Texture
        if (t == "Choose a Texture") {
            alert("Please Choose a Texture")
        }; /// end if 
        var c = $("#DropDownList2").val(); // Color
        if (c == "Choose a Color") {
            alert("Please Choose a Color")
        }; /// end if 
    }; /// end if  
  }); /// end function
}); /// end Ready
```

In fact they work directly in the page without the `$(document).ready(function () {` while it doesn't work at all either way in the external file.           An interesting tidbit, in the `#<%=RadioButtonList1.ClientID %> input')` the `<%` and `%>` are not yellow in the external file while they are as seen if directly on the page.  I know I am firing the external file as evidenced by the simple `$(document).ready(function alert("Ready")` working.
What am I missing, thank you.

Comment: which is the sequence of your files ? I think you jquery is loaded after thuis file

Comment: @SurenSrapyan The `alert` works, so jQuery is loaded.

Comment: `Js` files are compiled by browser. `Aspx` by server. Server understands that it is a server control and server control has `ClientID` poperty. Browser doesn't understand that.

Comment: Thanks everyone, while this did not solve my problem it let's me know not to spend anymore time on it since it is a known issue per the 'possible duplicate' posting.  I'll mark this as resolved and see if there is another way I can attack this.